# strong markov property proof in serfozo

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

In Serfozo's book, the Strong Markov Property is stated as ($*$):
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\cprob}[2]{\mathrm{P}\!\left[#1 \mid #2 \right]}
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\mathrm{P}\!\left[#1\right]}
    & \cprob{X_{\tau+1}=j_1,\ldots,X_{\tau+m}=j_m}{X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{\tau-1}=i_{\tau-1},X_\tau=i}\\
    &= \cprob{X_1=j_1,\ldots,X_m=j_m}{X_0=i}\tag{$*$}.
\end{align*}
where $\tau$ is a stopping time of the DTMC $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$.
I am confused about one point in the proof.

---

*Proof.*
Write $(*)$ as
\begin{align*}
    \cprob{A_\tau}{B_\tau} = \cprob{A_0}{X_0=i}
  \end{align*}
for
\begin{align*}
A_n&=\{X_{n+1}=j_1,\ldots,X_{n+m}=j_m\}\\
B_n&=\{X_{0}=i_0,\ldots,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=i\}.
\end{align*}
Now condition on $\tau$ so that by law of total probability we have
\begin{align*}
    \cprob{A_\tau}{B_\tau} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cprob{A_\tau}{B_\tau,\tau=n}\cdot\cprob{\tau=n}{B_\tau}.
  \end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
    \cprob{A_\tau}{B_\tau,\tau=n} = \frac{\prob{A_n,B_n,\tau=n}}{\prob{B_n,\tau=n}}.
  \end{align*}
But $\tau$ is a stopping time, so the event $\{\tau=n\}$ is determined by $X_0,\ldots,X_n$.
Thus $B_n = B_n\cap\{\tau=n\}$ when $\prob{B_n,\tau=n}>0$.
This fact simplifies the preceding display so that
\begin{align*}
    \cprob{A_\tau}{B_\tau,\tau=n} = \frac{\prob{A_n,B_n}}{\prob{B_n}}.
  \end{align*}
Now we can express the above display as multiplication of transition probabilities so that, cancelling terms, we obtain
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\prob{A_n,B_n}}{\prob{B_n}} = P_{i,j_1}\cdots P_{j_{m-1},j_m} = \cprob{A_0}{X_0=i}.
  \end{align*}
At this point, Serfozo ends the proof.
I am confused about what happens to the term $\cprob{\tau=n}{B_\tau}$.
Is it 0 except for when the events $B_\tau$ and $B_n$ coincide (in which case it is 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your book here [Basics of Applied Stochastic Processes](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-540-89332-5.pdf). The reason for your question is given below.

According to Definition 25 on p. 16, for any finite $n$,  the event $\{\tau= n\}$ is a function of the history $X_0,X_1,...,X_n$ up to time $n$. That is to say,
the   indicator function $1_{\{\tau=n\}}$ of the event that $T = n$  is a (measurable) function of the variables $X_0,X_1 , ..., X_n$, i.e., $1_{\{\tau=n\}}=g(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$.

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space. Note that the sets $\{ \tau  =k\}, k=0,1,2,...$, form a **partition** of $\Omega$ (mutually disjoint, and their union is $\Omega$).

**Note that**
\begin{align*}
 X_0(\omega)=i_0,...,X_{k-1}(\omega)=i_{k-1}, X_k(\omega)=i \ \ (\Leftrightarrow \omega\in B_k);\tag{$1$}\\
 1=1_{\{\tau=k\}}(\omega)= g(X_0(\omega), X_1(\omega),...,X_k(\omega)) \ \ (\Leftrightarrow \omega\in \{\tau=k\}). \tag{$2$}
\end{align*}
We can see from eq. (1) and (2) that for a fixed $k$, if there is some $\omega \in B_k\cap \{\tau=k\}$, then all those $\omega'\in B_k$  belong  to $\{\tau=k\}$
(**Notice that $(i_0,i_1,...,i_{k-1},i)$ is a singleton in the product space $\mathbb{N}\times \cdots\times \mathbb{N}$!**). That is to say, if $B_k\cap \{\tau=k\}\neq \varnothing$, then $B_k\subset \{\tau=k\}$, so that $B_k\cap \{\tau=k\}=B_k$.

Let
\begin{align*}
&S_1= \{n: B_\tau\cap \{\tau=n\}=B_n\cap \{\tau=n\}\neq \varnothing\},\\
&S_2=S_1^c .
\end{align*}
Hence, **for all those $n\in S_1$**, we have
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(A_\tau \mid B_\tau, \tau=n) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A_n,B_n,\tau=n)}{\mathbb{P}(B_n,\tau=n)} =\frac{\mathbb{P}(A_n,B_n)}{\mathbb{P}(B_n)}=\mathbb{P}(A_0\mid X_0=i), 
\end{align*}
and **for those $n\in S_2$**, $\mathbb{P}( B_\tau,  \tau=n)=0$.
That is to say,
\begin{equation}
 \mathbb{P}(A_\tau \mid B_\tau, \tau=n) =\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(A_0\mid X_0=i), & n\in  S_1;\\
0, &n\in S_2.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A_\tau\mid B_\tau)&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_\tau\mid B_\tau,\tau=n) \ \mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau)\\
&=\sum_{n\in S_1} \mathbb{P}(A_\tau\mid B_\tau,\tau=n) \ \mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau) +\sum_{n\in S_2} \mathbb{P}(A_\tau\mid B_\tau,\tau=n) \ \mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(A_0\mid X_0=i)\sum_{n\in S_1} \mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau)+0,
\end{align*}
**We need to calculate the term $\sum_{n\in S_1}\mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau)$.** Note that for those $n\in S_2$, according to our definition, $B_\tau \cap \{\tau=n\}=B_n\cap \{\tau=n\}=\varnothing$, so that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(\tau=n, B_\tau)}{\mathbb{P}(B_\tau)}=  \frac{\mathbb{P}(\tau=n, B_n)}{\mathbb{P}(B_\tau)}= 0.
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\in S_1}\mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\tau=n\mid B_\tau) =  \mathbb{P}\left( \left.  \sum_{n=0}^\infty\{\tau=n\} \  \right|\ B_\tau\right) = \mathbb{P}\left( \Omega\mid\ B_\tau\right)=1.
\end{align*}
Hence we have done.